# SQL IF no value found, add blank vlaue

Tags: mysql

I need some help with a query please.

```
SELECT wp_mailster_subscribers.`email` AS 'Email',
    Firstname_Table.`meta_value` AS 'Firstname',
    Lastname_Table.`meta_value` AS 'Lastname',
    FROM_UNIXTIME(wp_mailster_lists_subscribers.`added`,"%Y-%m-%d") AS 'Date Added',
    wp_mailster_status.`status` AS 'Status'
FROM wp_mailster_fa_details


INNER JOIN wp_mailster_lists_subscribers
    ON wp_mailster_lists_subscribers.`list_id` = wp_mailster_fa_details.`mailing_list`  
INNER JOIN wp_mailster_subscribers
    ON wp_mailster_lists_subscribers.`subscriber_id` = wp_mailster_subscribers.`ID`

INNER JOIN wp_mailster_subscriber_fields AS Firstname_Table
    ON wp_mailster_lists_subscribers.`subscriber_id` = Firstname_Table.`subscriber_id`
INNER JOIN wp_mailster_subscriber_fields AS Lastname_Table
    ON wp_mailster_lists_subscribers.`subscriber_id` = Lastname_Table.`subscriber_id`

INNER JOIN wp_mailster_status
    ON wp_mailster_subscribers.`status` = wp_mailster_status.`status_id`

WHERE wp_mailster_fa_details.`username` = '%CURRENT_USER_LOGIN%'
AND Firstname_Table.`meta_key` = 'firstname'
AND Lastname_Table.`meta_key` = 'lastname'
```

My difficulty lies with the Firstname and Lastname, if these are blank, they do not exist. Hence if they do not exist the entire row is not displayed.

How do I get it to display a blank value, instead of not displaying the entire row?

For example:

```
| Email      | Firstname    | Lastname     |   Status  |
--------------------------------------------------------
| some@email | John         |  Dirt        |  Active   |
| else@email |              |              |  Active   |
```

Comment: Incidentally, while it does nothing to improve performance, the following syntax can be easier to comprehend...  `MAX(CASE WHEN x.meta_key = 'firstname' THEN x.meta_value END) 'Firstname'
, MAX(CASE WHEN x.meta_key = 'lastname' THEN x.meta_value END) 'Lastname'
FROM wp_mailster_subscriber_fields x
GROUP BY...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are describing `left join`s:

```
SELECT wp_mailster_subscribers.`email` AS 'Email',
    Firstname_Table.`meta_value` AS 'Firstname',
    Lastname_Table.`meta_value` AS 'Lastname',
    FROM_UNIXTIME(wp_mailster_lists_subscribers.`added`,"%Y-%m-%d") AS 'Date Added',
    wp_mailster_status.`status` AS 'Status'
FROM wp_mailster_fa_details
LEFT JOIN wp_mailster_lists_subscribers
    ON wp_mailster_lists_subscribers.`list_id` = wp_mailster_fa_details.`mailing_list`  
LEFT JOIN wp_mailster_subscribers
    ON wp_mailster_lists_subscribers.`subscriber_id` = wp_mailster_subscribers.`ID`
LEFT JOIN wp_mailster_subscriber_fields AS Firstname_Table
    ON wp_mailster_lists_subscribers.`subscriber_id` = Firstname_Table.`subscriber_id`
    AND Firstname_Table.`meta_key` = 'firstname'
LEFT JOIN wp_mailster_subscriber_fields AS Lastname_Table
    ON wp_mailster_lists_subscribers.`subscriber_id` = Lastname_Table.`subscriber_id`
    AND Lastname_Table.`meta_key` = 'lastname'
LEFT JOIN wp_mailster_status
    ON wp_mailster_subscribers.`status` = wp_mailster_status.`status_id`
WHERE wp_mailster_fa_details.`username` = '%CURRENT_USER_LOGIN%'
```

Side notes:

- do not use single quotes for identifiers - they should be reserved for literal stings only
- do use single quotes rather than double quotes for identifiers
- table aliases make the query easier to read and write
- you usually don't need backticks around column identifiers

I would phrase your query as:

```
SELECT ms.email
    msf1.meta_value AS Firstname,
    msf2.meta_value AS Lastname,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(ls.added,'%Y-%m-%d') AS Date Added,
    mst.status AS Status
FROM wp_mailster_fa_details fd
LEFT JOIN wp_mailster_lists_subscribers ls
    ON ls.list_id = fd.mailing_list  
LEFT JOIN wp_mailster_subscribers ms
    ON ls.subscriber_id = ms.ID
LEFT JOIN wp_mailster_subscriber_fields AS msf1
    ON ls.subscriber_id = msf1.subscriber_id
    AND msf1.meta_key = 'firstname'
LEFT JOIN wp_mailster_subscriber_fields AS msf2
    ON ls.subscriber_id = msf2.subscriber_id
    AND msf2.meta_key = 'lastname'
LEFT JOIN wp_mailster_status
    ON ms.status = mst.status_id
WHERE fd.username = '%CURRENT_USER_LOGIN%'
```

Comment: I tried that, however my output results remain the same unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you for the side note. The program I am executing the SQL query in, wpDataTables, require the use of quotes as such. I tried formatting properly, and then did not want to execute at all.

Comment: Wow, your 'simplification' of my query, is magic! I have updated it as such, and now even the LEFT JOINS are functioning, where they previously did not. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

Just use isnull:

SELECT ISNULL(Firstname,'')...etc

Link for more info :
https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2015/10/how-to-replace-null-with-empty-string-in-SQL-SERVER-isnull-collesce-example.html

Comment: I tried the ISNULL function:

ISNULL(Firstname_Table.`meta_value`,'') AS 'Firstname',

I get the following error:

MySQL said: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'

Comment: However, the value returned is not NULL (as an empty value). It does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

you can change your query for select only Not NULL fields

ex-:

```
SELECT wp_mailster_subscribers.`email` AS 'Email',
    Firstname_Table.`meta_value` AS 'Firstname',
    Lastname_Table.`meta_value` AS 'Lastname',
    FROM_UNIXTIME(wp_mailster_lists_subscribers.`added`,"%Y-%m-%d") AS 'Date Added',
    wp_mailster_status.`status` AS 'Status'
FROM wp_mailster_fa_details WHERE Firstname IS NOT NULL AND Lastname IS NOT NULL;
```